# How to make SwiftData @Query updating from changes made on a background context?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-modelcontext

I have a SwiftData `@Query` in a `LazyVStack`, works nicely, updates on every model change, even if I make changes in relations only.

But I also have a long running task (~3 sec), so I created a `@ModelActor` for that and doing the work on a detached task.

But the view does not update.

If I start scolling, the newly scrolled-in items are already updated (they are probably queried fresh), but the existing items in view are not updated (not even if I scroll out and back). Only works after I restart the app.

**What do you do to update a SwiftData `@Query` after changes on a `@ModelActor` background context?**

> I tried saving the context when task is finished, manually update the view (with setting a new state after save), but it still shows the previous state.

Comment: “ when task is finished”, do you mean before the task was finished/completed?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Save is the last statement in the `Task.detached { ... }` closure.

Comment: Super similar to this [SwiftData background inserts using ModelActor do not trigger SwiftUI @Query view updates, but background deletes do](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734177). I'm fishing for people who experienced the same, and came up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By providing a custom `Identifiable` implementation of the queried models, even the on-screen items gets updated.

In my use-case the changes were made in relations, so I included the corresponding fields from relations into the `Identifiable` implementations as well.

```
extension MyModel: Identifiable {

    var id: String {
        "\(persistentModelID) \(relationship?.map { "\($0.persistentModelID)" }.joined() ?? "")"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for your Identifiable implementation? The default implementation is id: PersistentIdentifier. Does it update and not mess anything else when changing that?

Comment: @Affinity Sure, I updated. I don't think SwiftData uses the `Identifiable` implementation internally (yet SwiftUI is using it for diffing).

Comment: @GeriBorbás Thanks for adding the example! I already have a UUID as id for the model and this change throws an error due to re-creation of id.

Does this code mean that a new id will be generated every time a relationship is added? Or does it mean that Swift will use this `id` string just to compare the current ID vs the new if there is any change in the model or a relationship?

Comment: @Affinity I think it is the latter. This is just a computed property that SwiftUI asks when it is looking for views to be updated or not. I think this `id` won't ever read if you do not create a view that uses the model.